# How to convert the char[3] from an FLV struct to an int in c/c++

Tags: c, arrays, char, int

I have to read tags from an FLV file and there are three chars that identify the data length.  I've read them into char `dataLength[3]`, but I don't know what to do next.   It's binary, not ASCII, so it's not as simple as using `atoi()` to convert `char xxx[] = "123"` into the integer 123.  Here is my C struct for the tags:

```c
typedef struct {
  int previousLength;

  char identify; // 8: AUDIO, 9:VIDEO 18: SCRIPT
  char dataLength[3];

  char time[3];
  char timeExt;

  char streamID[3]; // always 0;
  char unused__;
} FLVTag;
```

I can read the tags from the file, but how do I convert `dataLength` into an int?

Comment: You can't just cast to int..? I'm not sure I understand what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: Do they three chars look like a decimal number, or is it binary?

Comment: Depends what's in the bytes.  Little-endian format?  Big-endian format?  ASCII decimal/hexadecimal/octal digits?

Comment: Why are you reading them to `char[3]`? Who told you it was a `char[3]` value?

Comment: What's the format of the data you store in the char[3]?

Comment: hi,dasblinkenlight.YES,it's binary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int length = ((unsigned int)xxx[0]) << 16 + ((unsigned int)xxx[1]) << 8 + ((unsigned int)xxx[2]);
```

Big-endian according to http://osflash.org/flv.

Comment: ...and the type of `dataLength` should be also changed to `unsigned char [3]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `int(char - '0')` to convert char to corresponding decimal integer. For example, `int('3' - '0')` = 3. In C++, you can also use string stream this way:

```
stringstream ss;
ss << char;
int n;
ss >> n;
```

Comment: thanks MMS,it's binary.not like convert char xxx[] = "123" to int value 123.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that. Can you write and example of the binary number? It'll be easier to talk about, then.

Comment: Thanks, I will edit the question to make it easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
int a = (dataLength[0]-'0')*100+(dataLength[1]-'0')*10+(dataLength[2]-'0');
```

if this char array have more item. you can use while loop;